# Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function in async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

***getRevenueByID*** function being called in ***async*** function, however getting an Uncaught SyntaxError. What am I doing wrong here?

```
(async() =>{

try {
    response = await fetch(mainURL);
    data = await response.json();

    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.results[0].title);

    ID_Array = [].concat.apply([], data.results.map(d => d.id))
    console.log(ID_Array);


    getRevenueByID(ID_Array);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
})();

getRevenueByID = (arr => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        console.log("ID is: ", arr[i]);
        getRevenueURL = await fetch('someurl' + arr[i] + '?api_key=YOUR_KEY&language=en-US');
        console.log(getRevenueURL);
        // let data = await getRevenueURL.json();
        // console.log(data);

    }
});
```

Comment: You can only `await` a function call from **directly** inside an `async` function.

Comment: You should get reference error. getRevenueByID is not defined at the time you call the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getRevenueByID` itself is not an async function.

"await is only valid in async function" means "directly in" not "called from somewhere back in the callstack".

So make it async:

```
getRevenueByID = async (arr) => {
    // ...
};
```

And then await it back where you call it:

```
await getRevenueByID(ID_Array);
```